# Database connectivity with GraphQL-Java

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

How to connect any database with GraphQL Application using GraphQL-Java implementation? Demonstrative approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible solutions:

A) Call the GraphQL query with the data object:

```
Foo data = perhapsFromDatabase();
ExecutionResult executionResult = schemaFactory.getGraphQL().execute(query, data, variables);
```

If data has a Method getTitle(), you can query that attribute directly in you GraphQL query.

B) Use a DataFetcher:

Example code from [GraphQL docs](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java):

```
  DataFetcher<Foo> fooDataFetcher = new DataFetcher<Foo>() {
    @Override
    public Foo get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
        // environment.getSource() is the value of the surrounding
        // object. In this case described by objectType
        Foo value = perhapsFromDatabase(); // Perhaps getting from a DB or whatever 
        return value;
    }
};

GraphQLObjectType objectType = newObject()
        .name("ObjectType")
        .field(newFieldDefinition()
                .name("foo")
                .type(GraphQLString)
                .dataFetcher(fooDataFetcher))
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I liked the best about GraphQL, it's a concept, like REST. So it's independent of technology. I've created a [**micro-blogging**](https://github.com/thekosmix/GraphQL-SpringBoot) application using **gradle, spring-jpa, spring-boot and mongo-db**. 
PS: I've also attached postman API calls to make it easier for testing.